# How to edit a row using dialogue box

Tags: sapui5

I have created a sap ui5 table with 5 columns where One of the column of table will have a button with edit icon.
I have tried as below:

```
 <Table id="table2" visibleRowCount="5" rows="{
        path: '/ProductCollection',
        sorter: {path: 'serialId', descending: false}
      }">
        <columns>
          <Column width="50px">
            <m:Text text="S.No" />
            <template>
              <m:Text text="{serialId}" wrapping="false"  />
            </template>
          </Column>
          <Column width="200px">
            <m:Text text="EmployeeName" />
            <template>
              <m:Text text="{employeeName}" wrapping="false" />
            </template>
          </Column>
          <Column width="200px">
            <m:Text text="EmployeeId" />
            <template>
              <m:Text text="{employeeId}" wrapping="false" />
            </template>
          </Column>
          <Column width="200px">
            <m:Text text="Age" />
            <template>
              <m:Text text="{age}" wrapping="false" />
            </template>
          </Column>
          <Column width="200px">
                <m:Text text="Email" />
                <template>
                  <m:Text text="{email}" wrapping="false" />
                </template>
              </Column>
          <Column hAlign="End" width="4rem" >
              <m:Text text="Edit" />
              <template>
                <m:Button icon="sap-icon://edit" press="editRow" type="Reject"/>
              </template>
          </Column>
        </columns>
        <dragDropConfig>
            <dnd:DropInfo
                            groupName="moveToTable2"
                            targetAggregation="rows"
                            dropPosition="Between"
                            drop="onDropTable2" />
           <dnd:DragDropInfo
                            sourceAggregation="rows"
                            targetAggregation="rows"
                            dropPosition="Between"
                            dragStart="onDragStart"
                            drop="onDropTable2" />
        </dragDropConfig>
      </Table>
```

On click of the edit button, a dialog box should open along with the data of the clicked row.

I have tried editing the row with the below function

where I am opening a dialog box with the current values , so that update on click of OK.
And this is my controller:

```
editRow: function(oEvent) {
      var oControl = oEvent.getSource();
      var oItemPath = oControl.getBindingContext().getPath();
      var oObject = this.byId("table2").getModel() .getProperty(oItemPath);

      var editRecord = oEvent .getSource().getBindingContext() .getObject();
      var editRecordRank = editRecord.Rank;

      var oDialog1 = new Dialog({
        title: "Wafer",
        contentWidth: "40px",
        contentHeight: "300px",
        content: [
          new sap.m.Text({
            width: "100%",
            text: "EMPid"
          }),
          new sap.m.FlexBox({
            justifyContent: "Center",
            items: [
              new sap.m.Select("EmployeeEditId", {
                width: "60%",
                items: [
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("itemee11", { text: "33" }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme12", {
                    text: "78"
                  }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("itemee13", {
                    text: "100"
                  }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme14", {
                    text: "75"
                  }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme15", {
                    text: "101"
                  })
                ]
              })
            ]
          }),
          new sap.m.Text({ width: "100%", text: "EMPname" }),
          new sap.m.FlexBox({
            justifyContent: "Center",
            items: [
              new sap.m.Select("EmployeeNameEditId", {
                width: "60%",
                items: [
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme1111", {
                    text: "test1"
                  }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme1234", {
                    text: "test2"
                  }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme1312", {
                    text: "test3"
                  })
                ]
              })
            ]
          }),
          new sap.m.Text({ width: "100%", text: "age" }),
          new sap.m.FlexBox({
            justifyContent: "Center",
            items: [
              new sap.m.Select("AgeEditId", {
                width: "60%",
                items: [
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme15211",  { text: "22" }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme136454", { text: "23" }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme213754", { text: "33" }),
                ]
              })
            ]
          }),
          new sap.m.Text({ width: "100%", text: "Email" }),
          new sap.m.FlexBox({
            justifyContent: "Center",
            items: [
              new sap.m.Select("EmailEditId", {
                width: "60%",
                items: [
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme11411", { text: "a@gmail.com" }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme34", { text: "b@hotmail.com" }),
                  new sap.ui.core.Item("iteme314", { text: "c@hotmail.com" })
                ]
              })
            ]
          })
        ],

        beginButton: new Button({
          type: ButtonType.Emphasized,
          text: "Update",
          press: function() {
            var otab = this.byId("table2");

            var rows = otab.getRows();
            var rowsLength  = otab.getBinding('rows').getLength();

            var tableArr = [];

            for ( var i = 0; i < rowsLength; i++ ) {

            tableArr.push({               
              empId : rows[i].getCells()[0].getText(),
              employeeName : rows[i].getCells()[1].getText(),
              age: rows[i].getCells()[2].getText(),
              email : rows[i].getCells()[3].getText(),               
            });

            }

            var employeeId= sap.ui.getCore().byId("empId ");
            var empnameId = sap.ui.getCore().byId("employeeName ");
            var ageId = sap.ui.getCore().byId("age");
            var emailId = sap.ui .getCore().byId("email");
            // data=oEvent.getSource
            var componentText =empId.mAssociations.selectedItem;
            var categoryText = empnameId.mAssociations.selectedItem;
            var quantityText = ageId.mAssociations.selectedItem;
            var mainCategoryText = emailId.mAssociations.selectedItem;

            var cValue = sap.ui.getCore().byId(componentText) .mProperties.text;
            var catValue = sap.ui.getCore().byId(categoryText).mProperties.text;
            var qValue = sap.ui.getCore().byId(quantityText).mProperties.text;
            var mValue = sap.ui.getCore().byId(mainCategoryText) .mProperties.text;


            tableArr.map(function(item) {
              if (item.empId==cValue){
              item.empnameId = catValue;
              item.ageId = qValue;
              item.emailId = mValue;
              }
              return item; });

            // var aContexts = sap.ui.getCore().byId("test");
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var oTable = this.byId("table2");
            oModel.setData({ modelData: tableArr });
            oTable.setModel(oModel);
            oTable.bindRows("/modelData");

            oDialog1.close();
          }.bind(this)
        }),

        endButton: new Button({
          text: "Close",
          press: function() {
            this.pressDialog.close();
          }.bind(this)
        })
      });
      oDialog1.open();
    },
```

any guiding links or a solution would be much helpful , TIA

Comment: I would recommend a few things: Don't create your `Dialog` with JS. Make an XML fragment, load that fragment and transfer the binding context to your new fragment. Also, why is everything in a `Select`? You cannot change the values in a select if there is only one value?!. Also there are getters to access the selected items, don't use the `mAssociations` attribute, it may change anytime.

Comment: i have few more values but didn't put that here , yeah sure i was looking for a sample to do this , i have seen demo sample which shows multi edit and it is little complex for me to understand the same

Comment: So what is the problem with your current solution? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I cannot update rows with the current solution though ....

Comment: I have updated my question which i have just tried

Answer (score 0):

The binding for the dialog is missing. Add the dialog as "dependent" on the view to be connected to the view’s model lifecycle. Or try to bind the element like this oDialog.bindElement(sPath). 
Try sth. like oDialog1.bindElement(oItemPath) before opening the dialog.

Comment: As you said i have binded the elements and getting an error as  Cannot read property 'bindElement' of undefined